# Why concurrent code takes more time to execute

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, go

I have a function named linearize...I'm trying to speed up its execution but surprised to find that it had become slower. Have I missed something or have messed up with fundamentals..

As per my understanding things should improve..

Thanks,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var rgb []float64

func linearizeWithWg(v float64, idx int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    if v <= 0.04045 {
        rgb[idx] = v / 12.92
    } else {
        rgb[idx] = math.Pow((v+0.055)/1.055, 2.4)
    }
}

func linearizeWithGoR(v float64) float64 {
    res := make(chan float64)

    go func(input float64) {
        if input <= 0.04045 {
            res <- input / 12.92
        } else {
            res <- math.Pow((input+0.055)/1.055, 2.4)
        }
    }(v)
    return <-res
}

func linearizeNomal(v float64) float64 {
    if v <= 0.04045 {
        return v / 12.92
    }
    return math.Pow((v+0.055)/1.055, 2.4)
}

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    const C = 1.0 / 255.0

    //Normal Execution
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        linearizeNomal(float64(i) * C * 0.5)
        linearizeNomal(float64(i) * C * 1.5)
        linearizeNomal(float64(i) * C * 4.5)
    }
    elaspsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println(elaspsed)

    //With GoRoutines.. Slow
    start = time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        linearizeWithGoR(float64(i) * C * 0.5)
        linearizeWithGoR(float64(i) * C * 1.5)
        linearizeWithGoR(float64(i) * C * 2.5)
    }
    elaspsed = time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println(elaspsed)

    //With WaitGroup. Slow

    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        rgb = make([]float64, 3)
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        wg.Add(3)
        linearizeWithWg(float64(i)*C*0.5, 0, &wg)
        linearizeWithWg(float64(i)*C*1.5, 1, &wg)
        linearizeWithWg(float64(i)*C*4.5, 2, &wg)
        wg.Wait()
    }
    elaspsed = time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println(elaspsed)

}
```

Comment: Make sure your `GOMAXPROCS` is greater than 1 — otherwise, all goroutines will be executed in one physical thread sequentially.

Comment: Code modified after @Dean Elbaz comments. http://play.golang.org/p/QemdM3ElsX

Comment: Concurrency is not parallelism. Concurrency is a way to think about code, not a synonym for "this runs faster". Albeit doing concurrency correct may help using all your cores.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The overhead of all the concurrency related functions(channel creation, channel sending, goroutine creation) is way bigger than the two instructions that you execute in each of your goroutine.

In addition, your goroutine version is basically serial because you spawn a goroutine and immediately wait for the result of its channel. The waitgroup version is similar.

Try again with a small number of goroutines each executing a chunk of your loop. @Joker_vD also has a good point to make sure that `GOMAXPROCS` is bigger than one.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you don't actually do anything concurrently.

in the workgroup example, you need to call `go linearizeWithWg(...)`

In the goroutine example, you start a goroutine, but then wait for it to end in the function. To run it concurrently, you would need a buffered response channel, and having another goroutine getting the responses

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the biggest blunder ... I did corrected that and again the I see no major benefit in executing it with *wg here are the some quick stats... Normal execution takes.. 38.ms and modified code for wg tooks 1.82s Now that I have also added code  `nCPU := runtime.NumCPU() runtime.GOMAXPROCS(nCPU)` Can there a overhead as suggested by @inf ?

Comment: Yes, overhead is possible. If there are lots of context switches back and forth that costs. Running in parallel makes more sense if the parallel routines each do bigger, long running calculations / processing. Small chunks of processing, and then a need for sync of another thread can then be very slow.